# MySql Server installation dont recognize python 3.4.6

Tags: php, python, mysql

I am trying to install MySql Server on Win 8 and as I go through the process, the installer requires Python 3.4 so I installed it manually with the given link of the installer.
I have installed Python 3.4.6 as it is the latest version but still it is not recognized and the installer returns an error message saying the "The requirement is still failing". 
Should I install Python 3.4 instead of 3.4.6?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Phyton 3.4 and uninstalled the 3.4.6 version and it worked, I don't know why but it worked